# Do we have a moral obligation to be informed of the news?

Tags: ethics, moral-skepticism

I have been reading a debate that took place in a few parts, here:  https://www.overthinkingit.com/2017/06/21/moral-obligation-read-news-part-1/

The debate mostly discusses whether we can choose to decline getting our news from a resource that is bad, and whether being too informed is harmful or beneficial.

I often find myself sitting with 2 of my best friends, discussing the news with one friend, while the other friend is completely against even acknowledging the news.

He or she are not declining knowing the news because of it coming from a biased source, but rather because they simply don’t want to be bothered with such knowledge.

Do we have any obligation to be at least informed with the news?

How informed should we be from local to global?

The news started with town gatherings in a square where the people got informed. I assume the people were obligated to gather together. Since no such obligation occurs in today’s age, I am curious as to how morally obligated are we to at least get informed of the news.

Comment: One is obligated to be informed to make decisions to which the information is relevant, say, to do their job or to meaningfully participate in elections. As long as the news are just FYI, there is no more obligation to know them than to read Shakespeare or listen to Bach, indeed, one may be more obligated to do the latter to be a well-rounded person.

Comment: @Conifold but how can one determine which information is relevant without going over the news ?

Comment: By using common sense to decide what can be reasonably expected to be relevant and worth the time and effort. And some relevant things will be missed one way or the other, as with any other task, humans have limited resources and are fallible.

Comment: @Conifold “ to do their job or to meaningfully participate in elections. ”  I assume that you should also be informed, in order  to make a decision  not to vote at all? Or is it morally accepted for someone to decide not to vote based on the lack of will to get informed?

Comment: These sorts of obligations are subject to pragmatic balancing. Even if one should ideally do A, B and C they are justified in neglecting A if B and C are more pressing concerns and/or promise better return on their effort. But *if* they judge that getting information relevant to voting must be deprioritized *then* they also have an obligation to refrain from voting (or some other dependent task).